# QUnit testing with Skatejs elements

Tags: javascript, testing

I'm using Skatejs for controlling event lifecycle. However, because of async loading, I'm having trouble with writing tests with QUnit.

```
setTimeout(function() {
     //assertions here
}, 5000);
```

I use setTimeout like above but then I got an issue with `Expected at least one assertion, but none were run - call expect(0) to accept zero assertions.`

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version you're using, you can approach testing in several ways.

Using your setTimeout() method to wait for mutation observers, you'd have to use [async tests](https://api.qunitjs.com/async/).

If you have access to the return value of the `skate()` call, then you can use that as a constructor to create your element synchronously.

In older versions of Skate you have [`skate.init()`](https://github.com/skatejs/skatejs/tree/0.15.3#init-elements) which is synchronous. In newer versions you have [`skate.ready()`](https://github.com/skatejs/skatejs/tree/1.0.0-beta.2#ready-element-callback) which is asynchronous.

If you're using the beta-soon-to-be-1.0 version, the v0 and v1 custom element polyfills will upgrade your element synchronously when you call `document.createElement()`.

EDIT

I've since been using https://github.com/treshugart/bore which makes testing web components (and DOM in general) much simpler. It also solves the async issues with polyfilled custom elements. Let me know if you end up using it and have any questions.